# XSLT test on xsl:template

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I've a xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<CategoriesList>
  <Category ID="1" >
    <Name ID="1395687" Value="Libelle1" langid="1"/>
    <Name ID="1395689" Value="" langid="3"/>
  </Category>
  <Category ID="2" >
    <Name ID="1395687" Value="" langid="1"/>
    <Name ID="1395689" Value="Libelle2" langid="3"/>
  </Category>
</CategoriesList>
```

I try to do a smart filter with XSLT file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output  method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="CategoriesList">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Category"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Category">
    <xsl:element name="Category">
        <xsl:attribute name="ID">
            <xsl:value-of select="@ID"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Name"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Name[@langid=3]">
    <xsl:attribute name="Name">
        <xsl:value-of select="@Value"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

I can filter to take only Name node with langid=3
But I want :
if Name node with langid=3 is empty take Name node with langid=1
if Name node with langid=3 is not empty take Name node with langid=3

I saw

Please, can you help me

Comment: "*if Name node with langid=3 is empty*" What do you mean by empty? All the Name nodes in your example are empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If "empty" means that the Value attribute is empty, try something like:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/CategoriesList">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Category"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Category">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:attribute name="Name">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="Name[@langid=3][string(@Value)]">
                    <xsl:value-of select="Name[@langid=3]/@Value"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="Name[@langid=1]/@Value"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your input example, the **result** is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CategoriesList>
  <Category ID="1" Name="Libelle1"/>
  <Category ID="2" Name="Libelle2"/>
</CategoriesList>
```

Note that we are assuming that langid is unique within each category.

Comment: exactly what i need. I'm a beginner on XSLT, but I learn lot of thing again.